# How to call back methods in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, gpio

I am making a project in which whenever I stop the stopwatch, it updates the time into a Listbox. It can be updated in the `self.m listbox`. However it cannot be updated into `topscoreslistbox`.

In the `printFunctionStop` function, i call back the Stop method in a class. However i do not know how to call the `TopscoresStop` in the main function.

The `Stop` method and `TopscoresStop` method do the same thing. However the different thing is one is in the class and one is in the main function.

So how do i call the method `TopscoresStop` in the main function in `printFunctionStop` anyone knows?

```
class StopWatch(Frame):  
    def Stop(self):                                    
        """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
        tempo = self._elapsedtime - self.lapmod2
        if self._running:
            self.after_cancel(self._timer)            
            self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start    
            self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
            self._running = 0

        if len(self.laps) == 3:
            return

        self.laps.append(self._setLapTime(tempo))
        self.m.insert(END, (str(self.one.get()) , "%.2f" % self._elapsedtime))
        self.m.yview_moveto(1)

def main():
    def Topscores():
        toplevel() = Toplevel()
        toplevel.title("Top Scores")
        topscoreslistbox = Listbox(toplevel, selectmode=EXTENDED, height=3, width=20, font=("Helvetica", 26))                   
        topscoreslistbox.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1, pady=5, padx=2)

        first = Label(toplevel, text=("1st"), font=("Algerian", 30))
        first.pack(side=TOP)

        second = Label(toplevel, text=("2nd"), font=("Algerian", 30))
        second.pack(side=TOP)     

        third = Label(toplevel, text=("3rd"), font=("Algerian", 30))
        third.pack(side=TOP)          

    def TopscoresStop():
        tempo = sw._elapsedtime - sw.lapmod2
        if sw._running:
            sw.after_cancel(sw._timer)            
            sw._elapsedtime = time.time() - sw._start    
            sw._setTime(sw._elapsedtime)
            sw._running = 0

        if len(sw.laps) == 3:
            return

        sw.laps.append(sw._setLapTime(tempo))
        topscoreslistbox.insert(END, (str(sw.one.get()) , "%.2f" % sw._elapsedtime))
        topscoreslistbox.yview_moveto(1)

    def printFunctionStop(channel):

        sw.event_generate("<<Stop>>", when = "tail")    

    GPIO.add_event_detect(16, GPIO.FALLING, callback = printFunctionStop, bouncetime=300)
    sw.bind("<<Stop>>", lambda event:sw.Stop())
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing the function as an argument to `printfunctionstop`?

sorry, can't make comments yet.

E.g.

```
def a():
    print('hi')

def b(func):
    func()

def main():
    b(a)

main()
```

The main should print 'hi'